# What is this date format found in url: 1350619200000

Tags: php, date

Does anyone know what date/time stamp format is in the following url (this is the stamp i believe: 1350619200000)?

http://www.genbook.com/bookings/slot/reservation/30184703/403542371/403542375/1350619200000?bookingContactId=493345670

I'm hoping to use PHP to convert the current day/time stamp to this format so that i can create a current link so the user is always brought to today's date and time for scheduling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called `timestamp` format(among programmers). look at the manuals [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) and [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) in PHP to get your desired format.

If you plan to use PHP, this is how you go about it,

```
 $timestamp = 1350619200000; 
 echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $timestamp/1000);
```

Getting today's date/time as `timestamp`, [time manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php)

```
  //multiply by 1000 to be used in javascript
  echo time() * 1000; //gives current time in timestamp format, ie. since Jan 1, 1970.
```

Comment: It's not Unix time(stamp). It's a variation on it, which is an important difference.

Comment: It is called timestamp in javascript (`milliseconds` since Unix epoch), thats why it needs to be multiplied by 1000 in PHP (`seconds` since Unix epoch)

Comment: Yes, but the idea it is "Unix time" is still wrong.

Comment: ok, what I meant was unix time in php. anyways, I edited my answer, since OP wants in JS format.

Comment: I removed my downvote because there no longer is incorrect information there. I would still suggest you do mention Unix time stamp (though saying it is based on or a variant of or something like that rather than that it is) because it helps make sense of what the number is and find more info about it.

Answer (score 5):

It's most likely a Javascript timestamp, which is milliseconds since Jan 1/1970:

```
mysql> select from_unixtime(1350619200000/1000);
+---------------------------+
| from_unixtime(1350619200) |
+---------------------------+
| 2012-10-18 22:00:00       |
+---------------------------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

The timestamp you're looking at is a milli-second precision timestamp.

This format is standard in Javascript, among other places. If you go to your web browser's console and type `console.log(new Date(1350619200000))`, you will get and answer similar to this: `Fri Oct 19 2012 05:00:00 GMT+0100 (BST)`.

However, if you're trying to process it in PHP, you may be having trouble because PHP uses second-precision timestamps.

The upshot is that if you want to take this timestamp into PHP, you need to divide it by 1000 first:

```
<?php
$ts = 1350619200000;
print date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $ts / 1000);
```

Likewise, if you need to pass a PHP timestamp to be used in Javascript, you'll need to multiply it by 1000 at some point for it to be usable there.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that's meant to be October 19th at 4am UTC, it looks like it's the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch (midnight January 1st 1970, UTC). It's the "native" date representation in Java and no doubt some other platforms.

I use [epochconverter.com](http://www.epochconverter.com/) to check this sort of thing.